# "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in Standardized Social Media Sharing Method

Tags: swift, delegates, share, option-type

I am trying to create a standardized social media sharing method inside my SocialMediaSharingDelegate.  Specifying an individual social media service like I do in the facebookShare method works perfectly fine.  So to extend this I created an enum with the possible service types and the shareOn method accepts any valid service name to perform sharing.

It seems straight forward.  However, when I run the code and click on a button that calls the shareOn method I get a runtime error.  The error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" occurs on the line let serviceViewController... right after the guard statement.

It also works fine if I replace socialMediaService.associatedService() with SLServiceTypeFacebook on that line which is strange because socialMediaService.associatedService() is used without issue in the guard statement.

I can just create separate functions for each service for now but that is not ideal in terms of code reuse.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Social

enum SocialMediaEnum : String {
    case Twitter = "SLServiceTypeTwitter"
    case Facebook = "SLServiceTypeFacebook"

    // This internal enum function returns the SLServiceType associated with the current enum value
    func associatedService() -> String {
        var serviceName: String

        switch self {
        case .Twitter:
            serviceName = "SLServiceTypeTwitter"
        case .Facebook:
            serviceName = "SLServiceTypeFacebook"
        }
        return serviceName
    }
}

class socialMediaSharing : SocialMediaSharingDelegate {

    func shareOn(let socialMediaService: SocialMediaEnum, sender: subclassedUIButton?, currentViewController: UIViewController) {
        guard SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(socialMediaService.associatedService())  else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Twitter account to tweet.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            currentViewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        let serviceViewController :SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: socialMediaService.associatedService())

        if let imageUrl = sender?.urlString {
            if let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: imageUrl  as String) {
                serviceViewController.addURL(url)
            }
        }
        currentViewController.presentViewController(serviceViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func facebookShare(sender: subclassedUIButton?, currentViewController: UIViewController) {
        guard SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook)  else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            currentViewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        let shareToFacebook :SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        if let imageUrl = sender?.urlString {
            if let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: imageUrl  as String) {
                shareToFacebook.addURL(url)
            }
        }
        currentViewController.presentViewController(shareToFacebook, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Generic solution for most bugs: Remove as much as possible from the code while checking whether the error still occurs. This way you can either find exactly where the error occurs and fix it, or find a real bug in the API/Language and report it. Your code reduced to a minimum is called [Minimal Working Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) and is very much more appreciated on StackOverflow and the programming community because other can focus the bug and don't have to understand your code first

Answer (score 0):

SLServiceTypeTwitter and SLServiceTypeFacebook are keywords so they should not have quotation marks in the switch statement.  The actual values they hold are "com.apple.social.(service name)".